# 2 different versions showing

Tags: magento-1.9

Having upgraded Magento via connect manager from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1 ALL was good and patched. I installed a search extension and site looked distorted, I quickly rolled back and files and database. Now I can't update because it says the version is already 1.9.3.1. But backend shows 1.9.2.4 and is missing the patches included in 1.9.3.1

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to upgrade to 1.9.3.1 via the Connect Manager that could be the problem in your case

Comment: It did  do the upgrade and all was showing fine. MageReport.com was even showing all patched up.

Comment: Interesting the release notes probably need an update then

Comment: Can you recommend a way to upgrade manually or another option?

Comment: First backup everything (seems like yo'uve already done). Then download a fresh install of Magento 1.9.3.1 and copy the files over your install. See how it goes